# How to get count only today's post in get_terms wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
$termscat = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'newscategories',
        'orderby' => 'count', 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => false

    ]);
```

I am using above code to get post counts and is returning all post but i want to filter data only by todays date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

SELECT count(post.`ID`) as count,rel.`term_taxonomy_id`,terms.name FROM `{$wpdb->base_prefix}posts` as post INNER JOIN {$wpdb->base_prefix}term_relationships as rel ON post.ID=rel.`object_id` INNER JOIN {$wpdb->base_prefix}terms as terms ON rel.`term_taxonomy_id`= terms.term_id WHERE `post_date` LIKE '$currentDate%' AND post.post_type='$post_type' GROUP BY rel.`term_taxonomy_id` ORDER BY count DESC

Answer (score 0):

`get_terms()` used to get terms not posts.

if you want to get posts of current date then you can use the code below

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'vehicle',
'date_query' => array(
    //set date ranges with strings!
    'after' => 'today',
    //allow exact matches to be returned
    'inclusive'         => true,
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can get more information on this https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
$today['year'] = current_time('Y');
$today['mon'] = current_time('m');
$today['mday'] = current_time('d');

$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'news',

    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $tex_name,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term_id,
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$total = $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: An explanation of how your code answers the question helps users determine if it applies in their case.

Comment: Jasbir you can't get today count from get_terms. That's why you can use WP_Query() with the current date then you get the total number post of particular taxonomy. I applied it already.